# how to access outlook form fields in c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I have to call outlook login form in c# because I have auto fill the username and password. Can I access username and password field?

Thank you.

Comment: Login dialog for an Exchange account? Or POP3/IMAP4/SMTP?

Comment: @ Dmitry Streblechenko I ve to auto fill SAP , office 365 too.generally i have to access the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

So are you trying to read or write the credentials? I don't know about SAP, but the Exchange provider does not let you pass the credentials. The best you can do is cache the credentials using [CredWrire](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375187(v=vs.85).aspx) function. The exact format of the data cached depends on the version of Outlook.